# How to interact with external camera on Android devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, webcam

I need to develop an android application, which could be installed on all possible Android cell phone/tablets. This application should get image from an external camera. The reason I can't use the camera on customer's phone is that I want the images captured by different customers to be consistent.

I don't know if USB connection is a solution. It seems that this requires the customer's phone all have USB OTG compatiability and the reality is that only few brands phones have this compatibility.

The other two options are WIFI connection and Bluetooth connection. For Wifi connection, is there need to have a router as a middle man to get the connection work?
Should I build my own WIFI camera or bluetooth camera? Or are there already any WIFI cameras or bluetooth cameras base on which I can develop my application directly? Thanks in advance. Any reply is aprreciated.